# Bit shift in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

May be I am too tired.
Why dont't the following display the same value?

```
int x = 42405;
System.out.println(x << 8);  
System.out.println((x &0x00ff) << 8);
```

The lower bits should be clear in both cases

Comment: And what is your output?

Comment: Works fine for me w/ a few values; for what isn't it working?

Comment: Sorry guys.Updated post for the type

Comment: Why should it display the same value?

Comment: @Carlos:That is what expected.I was wrong.It is clear now for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, I'm leaving the bottom part for posterity...

If `x` is `int`, then it's pretty simple: `x << 8` will have the same value as `x & 0xff` if and only if none of the "middle" 16 bits are set:

- The top 8 bits of `x` will be rendered irrelevant by the left shift
- The bottom 8 bits of `x` are preserved by the masking

If there are *any* of the "middle" 16 bits set, then `x & 0xff` will differ from `x` in a bit which is still preserved by the shift, therefore the results will be different.

I don't understand why you'd expect them to always give the same results...

---

I'm going to assume that the type of `x` is `byte`, and that it's actually negative.

There's no shift operation defined for `byte`, so first there's a transformation to `int`... and that's what can change depending on whether or not you've got the mask.

So let's take the case where `x` is -1. Then `(int) x` is *also* -1 - i.e. the bit pattern is all 1s. Shift that left by 8 bits and you end up with a bit pattern of 24 1s followed by 8 0s:

```
11111111111111111111111100000000 = -256
```

Now consider the second line of code - that's taking `x & 0xff`, which will only take the bottom 8 bits of the promoted value of `x` - i.e. 255. You shift that left by 8 bits and you end up with 16 0s, 8 1s, then 8 0s:

```
00000000000000001111111100000000 = 65280
```

Comment: Wouldn't 0x00ff suggest that the type is short?

Comment: @pablochan: Not necessarily. Basically it's entirely unclear - we'll have to hope that the OP actually gives some more information...

Comment: @user384706: I've edited my answer. You do realise that `int` is always 32 bits in Java, right?

Answer (score 4):

Below, x is > 0xff , and in one case you mask away the upper 3 bytes, meaning you
you do `(0x123 & 0x00ff) << 8` , which will be `0x23 << 8` And that is quite different from `0x123 << 8`

```
int x = 0x123;
System.out.println(x << 8);  //prints 74496
System.out.println((x &0x00ff) << 8); //prints 8960
```

And if x is a byte, it will get "promoted" to int before the shift, and if it's negative, it'll sign extend, and you get a whole lot of 1 bits set in the integer, which is masked away with &0xff in one case, and not masked away in the other

i.e.

```
byte x = (byte)0xAA; //x is negative
System.out.println(x << 8);  //prints -22016
System.out.println((x &0x00ff) << 8); //prints 43520
```